# Can't make overwrite of system_store_edit_form to work

Tags: overrides, frontend-model

I need to add extra fields in multi store edit view, but currently I'm stuck with extension code, and seems that extension is not loaded?

My xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lso_Adminhtml>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Lso_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <system_store_edit_form>Lso_Adminhtml_Block_System_Store_Edit_Form</system_store_edit_form>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

As far as I understand my class `Lso_Adminhtml_Block_System_Store_Edit_Form`

should be called for rendering and die()?

/app/code/local/Lso/Adminhtml/Block/System/Store/Edit/Form.php

```
<?php class Lso_Adminhtml_Block_System_Store_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Store_Edit_Form{

    public function __construct()
    {
        die(123);
    } 
}

?>
```

What I am missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Update: one more file /app/etc/modules/Lso_Adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lso_Adminhtml>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Lso_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Update: mangento version 1.9.1.1

Comment: can you please put your all module files ? it seems like above code is ok for me

Comment: @KeyurShah Actually thats it, only one Lso_Adminhtml.xml . I added it in update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so i just tried your code and it works fine, however the `die` function actually does not output anything.

Changed it to `Mage::log(123);` and i got an output in the system log. So it definitely works.

I even `echo 'hello';` just to be sure.
[image]

Comment: It works now, I had messed up some files in core. Thanks!